# How to use same url in routes for 2 different controller methods in a Laravel?

Tags: laravel, charts, routes, controller, apexcharts

I have a dashboard that shows 4 chart stats and an area chart. I know it's impossible to use same URI in routes such as this:

```
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'createChartStats']);
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'createChartMonthlyInvoicesAndSales']);
```

I haven't created the `createChartMonthlyInvoicesAndSales()` method yet, but is there a way I can still use `dashboard` URI so I just can display these charts on one page?

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\{
    Role,
    Product,
    Sales,
};
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('cashier')) {
            return view('cashier.dashboard');
        } else {
            return view('dashboard');
        }
    }

    public function showCashierProfile()
    {
        return view('cashier.profile');
    }

    public function isAdministrator()
    {
       return Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
    } 

    public function getLowProducts(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $products = Product::where('qty_on_hand', '<=', 10)->paginate(10);

            return Response($products);
        }
    }

    public function getTodaysInvoices()
    {
        $data = Sales::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString())
            ->where('payment_type', '=', 'credit')
            ->whereRaw('balance != FLOOR(0.00)');

        $stats = [ 'total_balance' => $data->sum('balance'), 'total_count' => $data->count()];

        return $stats; 
    }

    public function getThisMonthsInvoices()
    {
        $data = Sales::whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->where('payment_type', '=', 'credit')
            ->whereRaw('balance != FLOOR(0.00)');

        $stats = ['total_balance' => $data->sum('balance'), 'total_count' => $data->count()];
        return $stats; 
    }

    public function getTodaysSales()
    {
        $data = Sales::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString())
            ->where('payment_type', '=', 'cash')
            ->whereRaw('balance = FLOOR(0.00)');

        $stats = ['total_payment' => $data->sum('payment'), 'total_count' => $data->count()];
        return $stats; 
    }

    public function getThisMonthsSales()
    {
        $data = Sales::whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->where('payment_type', '=', 'cash')
            ->whereRaw('balance = FLOOR(0.00)');

        $stats = ['total_payment' => $data->sum('payment'), 'total_count' => $data->count()];
        return $stats; 
    }

    public function createChartStats() {
        $chart_stats = [
            'todays_invoices' => $this->getTodaysInvoices(),
            'this_months_invoices' => $this->getThisMonthsInvoices(),
            'todays_sales' => $this->getTodaysSales(),
            'this_months_sales' => $this->getThisMonthsSales(),
        ];

        return view('dashboard', ['chart_stats' => $chart_stats]);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it will create the conflict if you are using same URL

Comment: Yes, I know, is there other way that I can still have https://myweb.app/dashboard in my URL? I'm referring to the `/dashboard`

Comment: What would be the purpose of that?  Which route should match if you enter `yourdomain/dashboard` in the browser? and why?

Comment: Use _one_ route pointing to _one_ action and add as many charts inside that action/method as you want

Comment: To show createChartStats() charts, see screenshot: https://ibb.co/bQV34FF then a chart below such as this, see screenshot: https://ibb.co/qC0PvcN on the same /dashboard page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're breaking the MVC pattern here. That's what's tripping you up mentally.

Your Model holds the chart data. The controller fetches the data. Your view shows the data.

So if you want to show X amount of charts on the same URL, create X data fetching functions (preferably through the Model(s) - the M in MVC). You then fetch that data in the method that returns the view. You then return the data of all the charts (could be 1, could be 6) to the view. As you did before:

```
return view('dashboard', ['chart1_data' => $chart_data, 'chart2_data' => $chart_data]);
```

And then have your `view` decide what chart to show using `@if` and whatnot.

Comment: Oh correct, sorry about that. Thanks for the help @Stan Smulders